# PDFKit::NoExecutableError on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

## On my Rails environment logfile

`` PDFKit::NoExecutableError (No wkhtmltopdf executable found at `/` is not writable.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/unknown' as your home directory temporarily.
/home/ubuntu/rails-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf ``

> > Please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF):
> >       pdfkit (0.8.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:32:in `initialize'
> >       pdfkit (0.8.2) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:21:in`new'
> >       pdfkit (0.8.2) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:21:in `call'

I tried installing, as instructed using `apt-get`, but the error still persists.

ubuntu@server:~$ which wkhtmltopdf

`/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf`

ubuntu@server:~$ wkhtmltopdf --version

`wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 (with patched qt)`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

and create new file config/initializers/pdfkit.rb

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/wkhtmltopdf'
end
```

Comment: how do i know the path?  bundle show wkhtmltopdf right?

config.wkhtmltopdf = '/home/ubuntu/rails-app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.3.1'

still doesn't work

Comment: I used the wkhtmltopdf path based on `which wkhtmltopdf on the root directory`

    then this error showed up

```RuntimeError (command failed (exitstatus=1): /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 --print-media-type - -):
  pdfkit (0.8.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:71:in `to_pdf'```